# Custom UIButton showing border on iPad

Tags: ipad, xcode4

I have four custom UIButtons sitting in front of a UIImageView, but for some reason on the iPad it is showing a white border around them.  Essentially it's a UIImageView with a black gradient with four buttons on it.  Each button is the height of the image view and they show a white line on each side.  Is there a way to get rid of it?

The view was created on whatever XCode 4's version of Interface Builder is called.

Comment: Screenshot? It’s hard to diagnose a problem like this based only on a description.

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I created the button in code as follows:

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]
```

Which seemed to work fine on iPhone but on iPad I needed as follows:

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]
```